# How to order by multiple rows with each one are all descending without null?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I wanna make 3 rows are all descending

There're 3 rows ,2nd and 3rd came from row 1 
[image]

but it's not working as i wanted .[image]

as you can see this result that having null value due to i had order by rowA only

I wanna make 3 rows are all descending independent without any null just like this :
[image]

I've tried about using nulls last/fist  but it's apply for single rows
and fill some value into null value , it's not working too

I'm using oracle 11g and blow are my sql:

```
SELECT val,
(CASE WHEN AGE ='Mature' THEN val END) AS MATURE,
(CASE WHEN AGE ='Young' THEN val END) AS YOUNG
FROM info   order by val,mature,young desc
```

Could you please show me some advice?

many thanks!!!

Comment: What database are you using ? Please don't spam the tag. Please also share the query that you have tried

Comment: what do you expect if there is a null do you want to remove that entire row ?

Comment: absolutely not,i don't wanna remove entire row

Comment: Your data has something like 10 rows, so I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: There's a disconnect here. Your query only assigns a value to column `b` when `AGE = 'Mature'` and only assigns a value to column `c` when `AGE = 'Young'`, so logically `b` or `c` or both will always be null. They'll never *both* have values. If you still need an answer please show a query that matches the data, and show the input data.

Answer (score 0):

What you could potentially do is add the following line to your SQL statement:

```
WHERE
age IS NOT NULL
```

(this is assuming age is the column name)

That would remove null values.